# Finding convex hull of size 4 points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, divide-and-conquer, convex-hull

P is a point set whose convex hull CH(P) is known to have exactly 4 vertices. Assume that x-coordinates of the points in P are all distinct, and so also the y-coordinates. How we can find CH(P) in O(n) time?

Comment: Any of the O(n h)-time algorithms will do since h = 4.

Comment: The points that have the smallest/largest x/y values must be on the convex hull. So the only complication is if one of the points has the extremes in both dimensions, e.g. if a point has the smallest x and the smallest y.

Comment: Yes, There is my confusion. How to find another convex hull point in O(n) when one point has two extremes?

Comment: Let's say that the first pass finds a point P1 with (minX, minY), a point P2 with maxX, and a point P3 with maxY.  P1 is at the bottom-left corner of an axis-aligned rectangular bounding box. P2 is on the right edge, and P3 is on the top edge. So draw that picture, and ask yourself where the fourth point can be. Hint: it cannot be inside the triangle formed by the first three points, because then the hull would not be convex.

Comment: Is that in 2 dimensions? Please specify. You only mention x and y in your question, but the convex hull could be a quadrilateral in the plane, or a tetrahedron in 3d space, for instance